# how to send value from a tab activity to an activity through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send value from this activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends android.app.TabActivity
{
    String uid;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
     TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");  
     // Tab for ActivityOne
     TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
     photospec.setIndicator("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one));
     Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, TabhomeActivity.class);
     photosIntent.putExtra("uid", uid);
     // startActivityForResult(photosIntent,0);
     photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

     // Tab for ActivitySecond
     TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Today's Meeting");
     // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
     songspec.setIndicator("Today's Meeting",
                                          getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one));
     Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this,TodaysmeetingActivity.class);
     songspec.setContent(songsIntent);
     // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
     tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
     tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab  
    }
 }
```

to this activity..

```
public class TabhomeActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
TextView txtview,shwname;
String uid;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabhome);
    Intent intent = getParent().getIntent();
    uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
    shwname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    shwname.setText("Hi\t"+uid);
 }
```

can anyone help me?? Pls . Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is not working?  post LogCat from that passage plz

Comment: i am not getting the intent value in my TabHomeActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when sending:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
intent.putString("uid", uid);
```

when receiving:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
uid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("uid");
```

or (using bundle):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
    uid = savedInstanceState.getString("uid");
}
```

Comment: getting a null value when trying to diplay in text view in my TabhomeActivity.. :(

Comment: what does Log.i("uid", "uid = "+uid);  in send-activity get you?

Comment: null value is returned in log.

Comment: i guess it did work when you fixed that "uid" had no value :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
uid = getIntent().getExtras().getString(YOUR_KEY);
```

Similarly when setting your data to intent use

```
extras.putString(YOUR_KEY, YOUR_VALUE);
```

Comment: i am getting a null value. :(

Comment: @priya89 You get a null when you store and get values this way from the intent?

Comment: getting a null value when trying to diplay in text view in my TabhomeActivity